# CentOS: gdb hangs on __read_nocancel call

Tags: gdb, centos7

I am attaching with `gdb` to an executable that has been compiled with debug flags. `gdb` hangs on `__read_nocancel` call. If I run executable without attaching `gdb` then everything is fine and application exits normally with expected result.

I have done a bit of googling but I can't find anything concrete. Can anyone suggest any solution or workaround? Is this is a known problem?

**Edit:**

It turns out that library that I use forks and uses Python in the background. After I switch to `inferior 1` and continue then program hangs.

```
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/python2.7...
[Attaching after process 13040 fork to child process 13041]
[New inferior 3 (process 13041)]
process 13041 is executing new program: /usr/bin/uname
[Inferior 3 (process 13041) exited normally]
(gdb) inferior 1
[Switching to inferior 1 [process 12455] (/usr/bin/python2.7)]
[Switching to thread 1.1 (Thread 0x7fec1cee5740 (LWP 12455))]
#0  0x00007fec1bc8cf42 in fork () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) c
Continuing.
^C
Thread 1.1 "python" received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007fec1bcb6f70 in __read_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffff6db2f70 in __read_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff6d3fb14 in __GI__IO_file_underflow () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff6d41063 in _IO_default_xsgetn () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff6d32fdf in fread () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7a364ca in file_read (f=0x7fffeac4f8a0, args=<optimized out>) at Objects/fileobject.c:1084
#5  0x00007ffff7ac6345 in call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffffffef5e0) at Python/ceval.c:4352
```

```
[Attaching after process 18291 fork to child process 18293]
[New inferior 3 (process 18293)]
process 18293 is executing new program: /usr/bin/uname
[Inferior 3 (process 18293) exited normally]
(gdb) info inferiors 
  Num  Description       Executable        
  1    process 18271     /opt/cpp_stuff/tests/test
  2    process 18291     /usr/bin/bash     
* 3    <null>            /usr/bin/uname    
(gdb)
```

Comment: Is your application multi-threaded?

Comment: Can you add the name of your operating system to your question?

Comment: Hi I have updated the information, I also added relevant details.

Comment: Can you add the output of `info inferiors`? I think you may have two processes, both stopped, reading/writing a pipe.

Comment: I updated the post with `info inferiors`. I kind of found work around by setting `set follow-fork-mode parent` and `set detach-on-fork on`. It would be nice to know how to deal with this kind of situations when I have to keep `follow-fork-mode` as `child` and `detach-on-fork` to `off`.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible, but if there were a way to choose the `detach-on-fork` behavior depending on the context of the fork (e.g. `on` for a popen or subprocess call so that they run unimpeded), would that help?

Comment: Yes, I think it would help. Is there a way to do that? I think the most preferable way would to ignore all forks from certain library.

Comment: I need to think about it a bit. I see that I can `catch fork` and then execute a `set detach-on-fork on|off` command that, after `continue`, will affect the inferior created by that fork. So you can make a decision, using scripting functions such as `$_caller_is`, for every fork.

Answer (score 2):

> gdb hangs on __read_nocancel call. If I run executable without attaching gdb then everything is fine and application exits normally with expected result.

No: GDB is *not* hanging.

Your application (python) is blocked trying to [read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) from some `FILE`. The input `python` is expecting never comes, so it waits forever.

You haven't provided enough info for us to know what the first inferior is trying to read from, and why that input never comes.

Mark Plotnick's guess that you have another inferior (2?) which is stopped and is supposed to produce the output for which inferior 1 is waiting is likely to be correct. If so, you need to resume that other inferior.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. How come my application is not waiting when I run it with no debugger attached? How can I resume other inferior? `inferior 2` and then `continue` ?